# Lua - scripting - for a roblox battle royale game crate

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I recently started making my first game in roblox w/friends. I was coding some kind of box, so that when touched it would give you some sort of gun. I have tried some random tweaks but it never worked. Here is my code:
What it does is waits for a player to touch it then does the animation (which I have inserted into the script) and then generates a random number. Based on the random number, it determines what to give the player. Then it destroys the crate, so the player can't farm the crate over and over again.

```
math.randomseed(tick())

script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(hit)

    
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then   
        script.Disabled = true
    
        
        local player = hit.Parent.Name 
    
        local num = 0
        for i = 1,45 do
            wait()
            script.Parent.CFrame = ( CFrame.new(script.Parent.Position) * CFrame.Angles(0,math.rad(num),0) )
            script.Parent.Part.CFrame = ( CFrame.new(script.Parent.Part.Position) * CFrame.Angles(0,math.rad(num),0) )
        end
        num  = 0
    
        num = math.random(0,100)
        if num>-1 and num<5 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.XM1404:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<10 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.MP5:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<15 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.SPAS12:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<20 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.M9:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<25 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.M4A1:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<30 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.M32:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<35 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.GC:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<44 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.Riot Shield:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<60 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.Grenade:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<65 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.M60:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<70 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.AUG:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<90 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.PartHP:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<93 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.RocketL:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<97 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.Max Heal Potion:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<98 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.DaggerOfShattereedDimensions:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack
        elseif num<100 then
            local sword1 = game.ServerStorage.Pulse:Clone()
            sword1.Parent =     game.Players[player].Backpack   
            
        end
    
        script.Parent:Destroy()
    
    end

end)
```

**All of the guns are in server storage**

Comment: Sorry, but it just won't work :(

Comment: what is "won't work" supposed to mean? what is the desired outcome and what happens instead?

Comment: The desired outcome is that the crate is supposed to give a player (which touched the crate) a randomly generated gun and then disappear. What happens is that when a player touches it, nothing happens. Its like a prop/box for decoration.

Comment: Are each of these things `Tools`?

Comment: Yes, I made sure before asking.

Comment: and which part is not working? is the callback being called or is it not working as expected? remove all unnecessary code lines

Comment: It isn't working as expected. Also, I do not think there are unnecessary lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your script is inside a Part and not a Model. Touched only works for individual parts, not models.

In addition, I don't believe the way you inserted the weapon into the player's backpack would work. Instead of sword1.Parent = game.Players[player].Backpack, try using Roblox's GetPlayerFromCharacter method like this:

```
player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character)
sword1.Parent = player.Backpack
```

This method is able to get the player from the character, allowing you to access the player's Backpack. More info on this method here: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetPlayerFromCharacter

I would also like to suggest a much simpler way to do this that would not require so many if statements. I would suggest putting all your guns into a folder inside ServerStorage. You can define a variable for this folder in your script. Then create another variable that gets the children of the folder using Roblox's GetChildren() command. This will return a table of all the guns in the folder. Then we can use math.random to select an item of that table randomly.

An example of this would look something like this:

```
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local gunsFolder = ServerStorage:WaitForChild("GunsFolder")
local gunsTable = gunsFolder:GetChildren()
local randomGun = gunsTable[math.random(1, #gunsTable)]--# gets number of elements in a table
```

Another note I'd like to add that may be helpful to you as a beginner is to use debounce instead of disabling the script. Debounce is simply just using a boolean variable and an if-statement to ensure your Touched event only occurs after a certain time interval in between touches You can use debounce to make sure that the player can only touch the crate once. Here is more information on debounce: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Debounce

Hopefully this helps, feel free to follow up if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I'll try to see if this works. I've been trying to fix this for like 3 weeks now. :)